# How to add Google Play Game Services to AIR Game AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, google-play-services, google-play-games, ane

Hey everyone does anyone know how this can be done? Is there any ANE out there that actually works? I have tried Fresh Planets ANE with no success https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Google-Play-Game-Services

Then I tried Alextel69's ANE and I got the sign in to work perfectly but once I call on Leaderboards I get an immediate crash https://github.com/alextel69/google-play-game-services-ane

I am using Flash CS6 and Flash Develop my game is created with the Lates Adobe AIR 17.0 for Android Devices. Has anyone successfully added the google play services with any of these ANE's?

I have been at it for days now. Still no luck. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

I've used several of [Distriqt's native extensions](http://airnativeextensions.com/) and they all work like a charm - no bugs at all!

They recently released a [Game Services](http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.GameServices) native extension - both Google Play Services & Apple Game Center.

I don't want to sound like I advertise specific brand, I just got bad history with Milkman, and a great one with Distriqt, so.. you can give them a shot! :)

Comment: Hey @AndreyPopov thanks for the response. I have seen Distriqt's Native extension for Google Play Game services and wish I could use them. I just cant afford that at all with my current situation. I heard it was really good though. That is why I am trying to implement a free version of services. If i can find one. Thanks though!

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it's about free ANE.. Sorry to hear that. If you have any chance - take Distriqt's - it's one time payment.

Comment: Yeah i will def do that I was planning on that once I get enough money. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [as3gamegears ANE](http://www.as3gamegears.com/air-native-extension/ane-google-play-game-services/). Its works fine